# Messages with persistence get stuck in ActiveMQ embedded in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to integrate ActiveMQ within Tomcat. To that end, I used [this](http://blog.octera.info/2011/06/how-to-embed-activemq-in-tomcat/) tutorial (a little outdated, I know, but the best I found). I created a servlet that instantiates and starts a broker:

```
try {
  broker = new BrokerService();
  broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
  broker.start()
} catch (final Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I then created a simple Hello World example with a single producer sending a persisted message to a queue and a consumer retrieving the message, which failed. Both, producer and consumer, were able to connect to ActiveMQ and the queue but the consumer did not receive any message. However, after restarting Tomcat (and consequently the broker), the consumer received the message previously sent. Any newly created messages were again stuck.

I tried some non-persisted messages, which all arrived as expected. When sending a combination of persisted and non-persisted messages, the non-persisted ones arrived immediately and the persisted ones required a restart.

This is my (very basic) code for the producer and consumer:

```
final ConnectionFactory conFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndi.lookup("connectionFactory");
final Connection connection = conFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
final Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

final Destination destination = (Destination) jndi.lookup("MyQueue");
final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

final TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Hello World!");
producer.send(message);

connection.close();
```

```
final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);

final Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();

final Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
final Destination destination = session.createQueue("APP.JMS.QUEUE");
final MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

final Message message = consumer.receive(1000);
System.out.println("Received: " + message);

consumer.close();
session.close();
connection.close();
```

I tried transacted, manual-acknowledge, and auto-acknowledge mode for the consumer. I also tried directly creating ConnectionFactory and Destination (as in the consumer code) as well as JNDI lookup (producer code). All yielded the same result.
I tried versions 5.15.12, 5.15.11, 5.14.5, 5.11.0 and 5.10.0.

Any pointers what I did wrong or where I can find a more recent tutorial? I am aware of the [official docs](https://activemq.apache.org/tomcat#manually-integrating-tomcat-and-activemq) regarding ActiveMQ and Tomcat but they seem to be missing the essential parts.

Comment: Which version of ActiveMQ?

Comment: I tried 5.15.12, 5.15.11, 5.14.5, 5.11.0 and 5.10.0

Comment: Perhaps some inconsistent BrokerService construction. Starting the broker up with an activemq.xml can be easier to test and reproduce any ActiveMQ-specific outside of your specific runtime-- ie in a junit test.  Try starting the broker using this approach: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/assembly/src/release/examples/conf/web.xml ref: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-web/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/web/SpringBrokerContextListener.java

Comment: I am not sure what exactly was wrong. I switched to ActiveMQ Artemis and used your proposal of an configuration xml file, which worked. So thank you!